# Propane-water molar ratio

Tags: combustion, mole

> Propane gas, $\ce{C3H8}$, burns in oxygen to produce carbon dioxide and water vapour as follows:
>
> $$\ce{C3H8 (g) + 5O2 (g) = 3 CO2(g) + 4 H2O (g) + \pu{2200 kJ}}$$
>
> If $\pu{1.5 mol}$ of propane is consumed in this reaction, how many moles of $\ce{H2O}$ are produced?

I'm completely stuck on this question, I have no idea how to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Let's start with the *balanced* reaction: how many moles of water 1 mol of propane produces? You have $1~\ce{C3H8}$ on the left (reactants), and $4~\ce{H2O}$ on the right (products). Abstract from the energy, it's irrelevant here.

Comment: Wouldn't that be 4 moles of water produced?

Comment: Yep, 4 it is. Now if there is 1.5 mol of propane (e.g. 1.5 times more), how many moles of water would it be? Remember that coefficients reflect molar ratios.

Comment: 6 moles of water produced?

Comment: Exactly! $4 \cdot \pu{1.5 mol} = \pu{6.0 mol}$.

Comment: Wow. That was a lot simpler than I thought. Thank you!

Comment: No prob:) Remember to properly balance the reaction first, and then use the ratios between the participating chemicals, when you encounter this type of problems.

Answer (score 1):

The ratio between propane and water can be taken out of your reaction equation.

$$\frac{n(\ce{H20})}{n(\ce{C3H8})} = \frac{4}{1}$$

So if you burn 1.5 mole propane it will result in
$$\frac{4}{1} \cdot 1.5 = 6$$
mole of water being produced